# How to compute $P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}^3}>L)$

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, independence, binomial-distribution

Let $L >0$ be a constant and consider the random variables $\left(x_i\right)_{i=1}^n$ that follow a binomial distribution as $x_{i} \backsim \operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{k}{n})$, but they are not necessary independent from each other. The variables $k$ and $n$ are integers.

I would like to know if there is a way to compute the following probability:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{-3}>L\right)$$

I can think about Azuma theorem but it was given for $\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}>L\right)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Surely you noticed that no $$\frac1{x_i^3}$$ is a well defined random variable since $$P(x_i=0)\ne0$$

Comment: $x_{i}$ represents a number of nodes in my case that cannot be zero. So, I can use that form.

Comment: But you wrote that all of the $x_i$ are binomially distributed, which implies that they can be zero?

Comment: I can say that they are binomially distributed with the assumption that they can not take the value 0 right ?

Comment: @LinaHam not really. Do you mean that you rescale the pmf so all weights add up to 1 and all other values are binomial, i.e. $$\mathbb{P}[x_i=k] = \frac{\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}}{\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}}?$$

That's not exactly binomial distribution...

Comment: In fact, initially $x_{i}$ represents the sum of all nodes that are linked to the node $i$, and by assuming that the expected number of nodes linked to $i$ is fixed to $k$, then, it was clear for me that the sum of all the 1's  could be represented as a random variable that follow a binomial distribution $ Bin(n,\frac{k}{n})$ ..And in my case since the graph is connected then $x_{i}$ is never isolated so will never take the value 0.

Comment: @LinaHam Wishful thinking $\ne$ Rigorous mathematical setting.